# Trying to conditionally disable link depending on link text via javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link whose text content is determined by some backend software.  Depending on what the text content is, that link should be clickable or not clickable.  I am trying to make the link not clickable if the link text is "No New Messages".  I am trying to use the following code:

```
if ($('a#full_notifications_link').text() == "No New Messages"){
    $('a#full_notifications_link').click(function(){
        return false;
    });
}
```

This is not working.  The link works just like normal.  How do I get the link to not work if the link text is "No New Messages"?

To be clear, I CANNOT change any of the html because it will be different every time depending on the backend.  Also, I've determined the problem is with line 1, because if i place an alert right after it the alert does not appear.

Also, here is the html when the text says "No New Messages":

```
<a data-remote="true" href="/usernotificationslist" id="full_notifications_link">
    No New Messages
</a>
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me: [jsBin.com](http://jsbin.com/yiwayote/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/J8eEL/

```
$('a#full_notifications_link').click(function(event){
    if ($.trim($('a#full_notifications_link').text()) == "No New Messages"){
        event.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }
});
```

returning return false from a function doesnt usually do it..  event.preventDefault();

Comment: I can't change the href.  I can't change the link at all because it is completely determined by backend stuff.

Comment: Understood.. event.preventDefault then? can I see what HTML your db creates?

Comment: Hi, yes putting event.preventDefault(); will work then - please see fiddle in answer. @Philip7899 (also trim, as your HTML was generating with spaces.. Trim removes whitespaces)

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Do you by any chance know if there is a simple way to also make it so the cursor doesn't change to the hand when the link is clicked?

Comment: yep - see updated CSS Section in Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/J8eEL/1/

`a {
    cursor:default;
}`  @Philip7899

Comment: Thanks, you were very helpful.  Now I am having the opposite problem.  Feel free to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539281/trying-to-reenable-link-after-preventdefault-has-been-used .  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:myfunction();" id="full_notifications_link">text</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function myfunction(){
    var text_of_link = $('a #full_notifications_link').text();
    if(text_of_link == "No New Messages"){
        //do nothing  
    }else{
        window.location.replace($('#full_notifications_link').attr("href"));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i cannot change any of the html because it is produced by the backend and is different every time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have no spaces to meet the condition right..
To be sure, dont line break them

```
<a data-remote="true" href="/usernotificationslist" id="full_notifications_link">No New Messages</a>
```

also, have you already placed these inside?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //enter code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preventDefault to do this, by catching the click event

BTW this is not working to me i don't know why the onclick does not find the function to be binded hehe

Even though this the best approach I think http://jsfiddle.net/A2wns/1/

```
// HTML
<a href="..." onclick="checkMessage()">No New Messages</a>

// js
function checkMessage(evt){
  if ( $(evt.target).text() === "No New Messages"){
     evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
```